# Trouble connecting with Connman using dbus, but only the first time

Tags: python, linux, dbus, connman

I've been trying to use various Python libraries for working with Connman and the dbus, particularly this sample code:

https://github.com/liamw9534/pyconnman/blob/master/demo/demo.py

The problem I have is that when connecting to a WPA2 access point for the very first time, I will always receive a timeout message. For example:

```
CONN> list-services
CONN> agent-start /test/agent ssid=myNetwork passphrase=myPassphrase
CONN> service-connect /net/connman/service/wifi_xxxxx__managed_psk
```

Eventually this is the message I receive back from the interface:

> Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken

I can confirm at this point that Connman has no connected to a wifi network or obtained an IP address. The only way I can manage to get this to work is by using the Connman application itself from a Linux terminal:

```
connmanctl
connmanctl> agent on
connmanctl> connect wifi_xxxxx__managed_psk
Agent RequestInput wifi_xxxxx__managed_psk
    Passphrase = [ Type=psk, Requirement=mandatory ]
Passphrase? myPassword
connmanctl> Connected wifi_xxxxx__managed_psk
```

This creates a settings folder under /var/lib/connman for the wifi network. I can now use the demo.py script mentioned above to either disconnect or reconnect.

Connman is still a bit of a mystery to me in many ways, and I'm not sure why I have to use the interactive shell to connect to a network for the first time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're still looking for the answer :
Connman needs an agent to answer the security questions (in the WPA2: it's the password). You can either run an agent and reply to Connman questions or you can create a file in /var/lib/connman with the right keys. See [here](https://www.mankier.com/5/connman-service.config). Once a file is created or deleted Connman will auto magically act accordingly (try to connect or disconnect.

A basic file would look like:

> ```
> [service_mywificonfig]
> Type = wifi
> Security = wpa2
> Name = myssid
> Passphrase = yourpass
> ```

Comment: Thanks what would be the solution for the hidden network?

Comment: Just add to the file: Hidden=true